# Couchbase XDCR and haproxy

Tags: couchbase

I intend to setup a Couchbase system with two cluster: the main cluster is active and another one for backup (use XDCR to replicate). Use haproxy in front of this Couchbase system to switch (manual) from active cluster to backup cluster when active cluster down.

Before test, i want to ask some advice for this topology. Is there any problem with this. Can i run smoothly in production environment???

I thought i can not use vbucket awareness client in this topology. Because client only know haproxy, i can not send direct request from client to couchbase server (has vbucket for specific document). Is that right???

Answer (score 3):

From your scenario it sounds like overhead. Why would you keep "stand by" cluster as a backup?

Instead, you can have all four instances of couchbase servers as one cluster (each instance running on its own box)...so you will take full advantage of vBucket architecture that it will be native-managed. If one of the instances is down, you will have no loss of data since the enabled replication will have mirror copy in the other nodes.

We use this setup in production with no issues. From time to time we bring one of the instances down for maintenance and the rest of the cluster still runs and its completely transparent to the Couchbase clients, e.g. no down time!

In my opinion XDCR makes sense for geographically separated locations (so you keep one cluster in Americas another in EMEA and so on). If all your instances in the same location, then Couchbase cluster technology will deliver high-availability (HA) with fail-over support already build in.

Comment: I know Couchbase cluster already build-in HA but i afraid entire cluster down and i have to rebuild overall (long downtime - I met this case with membase cluster old version).

Comment: "entire cluster down" - if it contains many instances installed on separate hardware...I don't see it happening...unless fire/flood on premises. If you have backup cluster on the same premises - its no use for DR.

Comment: We are looking at a similar solution where the two clusters are in geographically separate locations, but we want the location of the 'active' cluster to be agnostic to the client apps.

Comment: @AndrewBickerton check out latest XDCR plugin filtering (long awaited feature now available). You can decide what documents in the bucket to replicate to the DR site.
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.0/xdcr/xdcr-filtering-setup.html

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately filtering doesn't solve the problem of how to manage 2 couchbase clusters with seamless failover :-( (useful to know though)

Comment: @AndrewBickerton you should post a new question with your use case and problem statement.